# Piecewise linear functions in constructive mathematics

Tags: constructive-mathematics, piecewise-continuity

Is is possible to constructively prove that, for any function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ piecewise linear, the absolute value $|f|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is also piecewise linear ?

"Constructively" is for example in the sense of Bishop's constructive mathematics, not in the sense of algorithms (recursive functions).

Piecewise linear can either mean to produce an ordered list of real numbers $a_1<\dots <a_n$ such as $|f|$ is linear on each $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$, or produce an unordered list of corner functions (only 1 angular point) of which $|f|$ is the sum. In both cases, the number of angular points of $f$ and $|f|$ is assumed to be finite.

It seems hard, because that would require to exactly compare the values of $f$ with $0$, to know when to insert angular points $a_i$ for $|f|$. Such a comparison of real numbers is not constructive.

Even on a single interval, $f : [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ linear, it seems hard. If there is a point $c\in \, ]a,b[$ such as $f(c)=0$, then $|f|$ is piecewise linear on the subdivision $a<c<b$. Otherwise $|f|$ is piecewise linear on $a<b$. Constructively you would need to know which case it is, but then you would need to exactly compare $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ with $0$.

Comment: It is constructive for _linear_ functions on an interval, though. Isn't it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean an algorithm? For example the input would be the collection of intervals and the expression of the function on them, and the output would be the same for $|f|$. There is the problem that there could be infinitely many intervals.

Comment: How can yo produce an ordered list of real numbers, when comparison is not constructive?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You assume that ordered list given by $f$, then can hope to use that information on orders to insert new angular points for $|f|$. But actually the 1-interval case suggested by Arthur is almost a proof that this question is impossible I think.

Comment: Is perhaps the use of absolute value of a number allowed (perhaps in the form $|x|:=\sqrt{x^2}$)? That would also give us max and min and might be used to construct $|f|$ with possibly some redundant support points ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes the absolute value is constructive. It is usually defined as the uniformly continuous completion of the absolute value of the rational numbers. It does give min and max as you mention, and redundant points are allowed, but I don't think that helps much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that a function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is *somewhere linear* if there are rational numbers $p < q$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $[p, q]$ is linear. Note that every piecewise linear function is somewhere linear. I claim that it is not constructively provable that $|f|$ is somewhere linear whenever $f$ is linear.

It is consistent with Bishop style constructive mathematics that continuous choice holds: that if $(\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})\phi(\alpha, n)$, then there is a continuous function $F \colon \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^ \mathbb{N}$, we have $\phi(\alpha, F(\alpha))$. It follows that the same is true if we take the domain to be $2^\mathbb{N} \times 2^\mathbb{N}$, ie given $(\forall \alpha, \beta \in 2^\mathbb{N})(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})\phi(\alpha, \beta, n)$ we have continuous $F \colon 2^\mathbb{N} \times 2^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. I'll show that the above statement is non constructive, by showing it contradicts continuous choice.

Given $\alpha, \beta \in 2^\mathbb{N}$, write $a$ for $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \alpha(i) 2^{-i}$ and $b$ for $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \beta(i) 2^{-i}$. Then there exists a natural number encoding rationals $p, q$ such that the function $f(x) := | a x + b |$ is linear on $[p, q]$, by assumption. By continuous choice, in particular continuity at the point $(\lambda n.0, \lambda n.0)$, we have a single choice of rational numbers $p, q$ and a natural number $N$ that whenever $\alpha(n) = 0$ and $\beta(n) = 0$ for $n < N$, $| a x + b |$ is linear on $[p, q]$. However, this gives a contradiction, because for any given $p < q$ we can find $\alpha, \beta$ with $\alpha(n) = \beta(n) = 0$ for $n < N$, such that the corresponding function $a x + b$ crosses the $x$-axis between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. That is probably the reason why Bishop's constructive measure theory starts with continuous functions with compact support, instead of continous piecewise-linear functions with compact support. The latter are not constructively stable by absolute value.